# Only display "Are you new" in the help center, if you don't have the “informed” badge

Tags: feature-request, login, help-center, tour

This banner shows when I visit the help center; whether I am logged in or not. This is on a site where I have almost 7k rep, and I'm not new to Ask Ubuntu at all...

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<sup>(Click for full page image)</sup>

Please could this be disabled if you have the informed badge, or you have a set amount of rep (maybe 200, when you get the association bonus).

There isn't even a close button like there is on the front page when not logged in:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Didn't see what? The dupe?

Comment: Nope, it was always there.

Comment: The purpose for including pronoun preferences is so that the correct pronoun can be used in subsequent discussion of the post content.  That happens mainly when a post is new.  Old, inactive questions aren't likely to encounter an issue of wrong pronoun choice.  This site, alone, has almost 91,000 questions.  If everyone starts editing their old posts just to add pronoun preferences, it will drown new activity and make the site unusable.  It might be preferable to be selective in editing old posts.  Thanks.

Comment: Kindly consider putting usernames in your profile first. I am more than happy to see it there. Also, there's Glorfindel's script which puts it in user card too. hope you're aware of this, or are you just trolling?